# how to get rows value in one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Select id
from x
```

gives a list of ids:

```
1
2
3
44
655
31
```

how Do i get it in one row as array? like `(1,2,3,44,655,31)`

Comment: Check the answer by evil33 and if that works for you, then accept the answer so the question will be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be like this

```
 SELECT string_agg(id, ',') FROM x
```

Comment: ERROR:  function string_agg(integer, unknown) does not exist

Comment: which version of postgresql you are using ?

Comment: I assume it should be `string_agg(id::text...` for example. PostgreSQL doesn't convert types unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/efe3e/3)**</kbd>

```
SELECT 
array_to_string(array_agg(id),',') as agg_id 
from x
```